# Can I hide the synopsis of the current or upcoming episodes of a series?

Tags: netflix, silverlight

When a Netflix show is paused, eventually the synopsis of the current episode will show on-screen. Also, when you roll over the "next" icon ( ▶| ), the synopsis of the next episode will show on-screen.

Is it possible to disable either or both of these synopses?

To be more specific, I am watching Breaking Bad for the first time. However, whenever I need to pause or I accidentally roll over the Next Episode button, I end up learning things about the current or upcoming episode that I didn't know, yet. While the spoilers are limited, they are still spoilers. Is there any way to prevent these occurrences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is now possible for many users to watch Netflix via an HTML5 player instead of Silverlight, new solutions are now possible.

For example, the Flix Plus by Lifehacker extension (http://lifehacker.com/flix-plus-customizes-netflix-to-your-hearts-desire-1640968001) which I wrote will hide some text/images and blur out others and only show them while you mouse over them.

Comment: This is an excellent solution! Fantastic plugin!

Answer (score 5):

(I know this is an old question, but replying just in case anyone else is having the same issue)

Currently, there's no way to do so in Netflix, but you can do it with the browser extension AdBlock. Add any or all of the following to your custom filter list:

Hide synopsis in episode loading screen:

```
www.netflix.com##P[class="player-postplay-episode-synopsis"]
```

Hide synopsis in pause screen:

```
www.netflix.com##DIV[class="content"]
```

Hide synopsis in next episode button:

```
www.netflix.com##DIV[class="player-next-episode-description"]
```

Hide synopsis in episode selector:

```
www.netflix.com##P[class="episode-list-synopsis"]
```

Comment: works like a charm. thanks!

Comment: Following the same logic, the new commands are (tested with AdblockPlus): Episode loading: `netflix.com##.WatchNext-episode-synopsis`, pause screen: `netflix.com##.nfa-fs-1-6-em.nfa-c-gray-80.nfa-m-0.nfa-w-60`, Netflix main menu: `netflix.com##.synopsis`, episode list: `netflix.com##.episodeSynopsis`

Comment: This line works (as of 2023-03-19) for blocking the episode synopsis when paused on a Netflix video:
`netflix.com##P[data-uia="evidence-overlay-synopsis"]`

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is currently not possible. Netflix has no such options currently.

As a way around you can install some third party extensions such as "Page Eraser" which can hide certain elements from certain sites from appearing on your screen.

Comment: The Netflix application is made in Silverlight. Would Page Eraser work on it?

Comment: @Koviko I do not know, I use neither Netflix nor Page Eraser and have no Idea what Silverlight is.

Answer (score 1):

The is no way to get what you want with their current tools, but these are some tips that could help you:

- Instead of pausing an episode, go back to the main menu. When you resume your show, it'll start playing from where you left. There will be no summary of anything. It's the same as pausing, but you won't see the pause screen.
- Just be weary of your mouse movements and focus your view on the icons/tools you want to use. You are not going to read text that easily from the corner of your eye.

If you feel you have any suggestions how Netflix can do a better job, try to contact their support service. They have 24/7 chat support, are very friendly and try to look for a solution that would fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I just set this up for myself today and I'm doing something slightly different than the other responses here, in that instead of an adblocker I'm using the [User Javascript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld?hl=en) extension. I use this on various sites to make small JS or CSS tweaks.

For https://www.netflix.com/, in the CSS section of the extension I have the following snippet:

```
.ltr-1642hdv {
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

This blurs the synopsis while still showing the title as well as episode title and number:
[image: Netflix episode spoilers blurred on pause screen]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the synopsis in the chapters list add this line:

```
www.netflix.com##P[class="titleCard-synopsis previewModal--small-text"]
```

In my case I am using uBlock Origin and works perfectly.